# Getting info. about a date with no year in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a five character wide column of data that consist of a date with no year such as: 04-17 or 11-22. I am trying to create a MySQL query that will give me day of year for values in this column but am having problems because the values have no year. The closest I've come is

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(YEAR(CURDATE())-t.sdate) FROM tablex t;
```

but the concactenation does not seem to work. Any ideas how I can go about getting the Day of Year for date values such as these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want concatenation, you have to ask for it explicitly [with `CONCAT()`.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',t.sdate)))
```

will do what you want, with reference to the present year. That makes a difference because some years are leap years.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get an accurate DayOfYear from just a day / month pairing. You need the year to determine if it a leap year or not. You can fudge it, but it will be wrong every four years.